# Download an excel file behind login (rvest)

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to download excel files that are stored behind an intranet that requires a login. All's working well except when I try to download the file. I am using `rvest`.
The example below uses dummy data:

```
my_intranet = "www.mywebsite_login.com"
the_excel_file = "www.mywebsite_login.com/excel.xlsx"

session =  session(my_intranet)
form = html_form(session)[[1]]
fl_fm = html_form_set(form, sUserName = "XXXXXX", sPassword = "XXXXXXX")
main_page = session_submit(session, fl_fm) 

b = session_jump_to(main_page, the_excel_file)
writeBin(b, basename(the_excel_file))
```

When I execute:

```
b = session_jump_to(main_page, the_excel_file)
```

I get the following `curl` error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Could not resolve host: NA
```

Any idea about what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified that `main_page` and `session` have valid values?

Comment: Yes! I manage to “jump_to” pages within the website and get attributes I am interested in, like the links to files to download. But when I try to download I get that curl error.

Comment: Tough to diagnose without being able to experiment. Seems likely to me there's something amiss in `main_page` or `the_excel_file`. Could be as small as an errant backslash. Frustrating, I know, especially as you've done the hardest part, in my view, and that's managing the session login.

Comment: Thanks anyway, for taking the time.